# How to set custom icons with bootstrap nav tree using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the bootstrap nav tree with angularjs, I want to set the custom icons instead of default, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you using http://nickperkinslondon.github.io/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/test/bs2_ng115_test_page.html

Comment: There is already present like that in my theme , and not sure that it is the same.

Comment: At least add some sample code and add icon images you want to replace with?